# Creation of symlink from job logs to ${hadoop.tmp.dir} failed in hadoop multinode cluster setup

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing

When I run simple wordcount example in 3 node clustered hadoop, I got the following error. I checked all write/read permissions of necessary folders. This error does not stop mapreduce job but all workload gone to one machine in the cluster, other two machines gives same error above when a task arrives them.

```
12/09/13 09:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201209121718_0006_m_000008_0,Status : FAILED
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Creation of symlink from /hadoop/libexec/../logs/userlogs/job_201209121718_0006/attempt_201209121718_0006_m_000008_0 to /hadoop/hadoop-datastore
/mapred/local/userlogs/job_201209121718_0006/attempt_201209121718_0006_m_000008_0 failed.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLog.createTaskAttemptLogDir(TaskLog.java:110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskController.createLogDir(DefaultTaskController.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.prepareLogFiles(TaskRunner.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:228)

12/09/13 09:38:37 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://peter:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201209121718_0006_m_000008_0&filter=stdout
12/09/13 09:38:37 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://peter:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201209121718_0006_m_000008_0&filter=stderr
```

What is that error about?

Comment: Can you share your Hadoop configuration files?

Answer (score -1):

java.lang.Throwable: Child Error

org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)

It seems the memory allocated for the tasks trackers is more than the nodes actual memory. Check this link [Explanation](https://github.com/wbsg/ldif/wiki/Hadoop-troubleshooting)